# How to distinguish Table from View in T4 template for Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I've successfully achieved this goad in T4 template for EF 4 by referring to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/977782c7-c970-42a7-8df9-f6682d4a327c/how-can-i-distinguish-database-table-and-view-in-t4-script?forum=adodotnetentityframework), but I'm working on T4 template for EF 6 now, does any body know any good solution? I've been suffering kinds of issues when I was trying to use the same code to do it for EF 6.